# Terminate SSH from terminal MAC

Tags: macos, ssh, terminal

I have in the past used terminal on mac to access a SSH to my website. However, each time I try to open terminal I'm autologged in. And I can't log out / exit to use the terminal. It's always "inside the shell".

When I try "exit" or "logout" or "ctrl + d" it logs out and I get a "[Process completed]". However, I can't use the terminal, nothing happens when I press any keys.

So I quit terminal and restart it, and I'm back at square one, logged into the SSH. I want to use the terminal application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When logged into the server via you could get the `tty` PID by doing.

> ps ef

Then just use kill, like;

> kill -9 **PID**

This will kill the connection from you and server.

Answer (score 0):

I have never test it before but with a quick search, I found two articles, [first article](https://withoutink.com/technology/how-to-auto-login-to-an-ssh-connection-with-terminal/) and [second article](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/21/change-shell-mac-os-x/).

First article mention about alias (which is ssh login without using password to remote server). You can try to check if there is alias created in your .bashrc file and remove it if it does have.

Second article mention about changing your terminal behaviour, which is most likely in your case. The article mention that you can check what is your default shell path.

Step to check your shell path:

```
- Go to terminal and open preferences
- Under General tab, you will see 'Shells open with'
- If it is under default then you might want to check '/usr/bin/login' and '/bin/bash', if there is anything that run the above alias and remove it if there is.
- If it is under Command(complete path), then you might want to check the path, if there is anything that run the above alias and remove it if there is.
```

I repeat, I have not tested this as I don't have this issue, but I hope this will help you solve the your issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: Yeah read them but those didn't help. I also tried the "shells open with" but im still logged in to the shell. I have no knowledge about this stuff. i followed a guide how to connect to my website to download files from it. And now im stuck there :S